# INSERTAR SOLO UN REGISTRO

Tags: sql-server

Necesito que solo se pueda insertar un registro en la tabla  es decir que si yo mando dos insert solo acepte uno y el otro lo rechace,
estoy cogiendo el ultimo lote de la tabla que va en el 18290, si inserto el lote siguiente que es el 18291 debe dejar insertar y así sucesivamente.
pero si mando dos insert que serian el lote 18291 y 18292 no debe dejar insertar el 18292 si no solo el 18291 es decir que solo deje insertar el que sigue

scrip que llevo

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Lotes_Restringidos] 
ON  [dbo].[tbllotes] FOR INSERT 
AS

   DECLARE @Lote NVARCHAR(10)

SELECT TOP(1) @Lote = max(codlote) FROM tbllotes GROUP BY FECHA ORDER BY FECHA DESC 
          
   IF (@Lote = @Lote +1)  
   BEGIN

       ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
       RAISERROR ('no se puede insertar mas de un lote .',
                                                -- Message text.  
                  16,                           -- Severity.  
                  1                             -- State.  
                  ) 
   END
```

El problema con el scrip es que deja insertar mas de un registro cuando solo debe dejar insertar el que sigue

**problema**

en un servidor **X** tiene una base de datos que es la que recoge la información de una app que hay dentro de un proceso de alimentos seria la bd de datos de origen, que la primare acción es crear un lote, ese lote tiene una **X** cantidad de productos, Lote **1485** tiene **1000** productos esos mil productos tienen  un peso, al terminar de pesar cada producto de este lote lo cierran, cuando lo cierran se ejecuta un paquete de **SSIS** que manda los datos del servidor **X** al servidor **Y**, el servidor **Y** tiene la misma base de datos con la misma estructura, este servidor se encarga de sacar informes pero liquida de a uno en uno es decir si desde el paquete me envían dos lotes en una sola ejecución y  en la bd de origen va en el **1485**  quedaría en **1487** y se perdería la información del **1486**, por eso en la base de datos de destino tengo que aceptar solo de a uno si el paquete me manda **2** o **3**, tengo que decir espera mándame el   **1486** y en la próxima ejecución el **1487**

Comment: Cual seria el problema con este script?

Comment: Que deja insertar mas de un registro, inserto dos registros de tacada y los deja insertar cuando solo debería dejar meter el siguiente

Comment: pero dos insert por separado son dos insert.. vos queres eso de que forma? porque este trigger se ejecuta para cada insert..

Comment: lo que pasa es que a esta tabla le llegan datos desde un paquete de SSIS, desde los datos de origen mandan varios lotes, pero en en el destino solo puede ir aceptando uno por ejecución, lo que estoy intentando es que cuando el paquete me mande varios lotes con el trigger voy aceptando de a uno en uno

Comment: No hay forma que puedas manipular las filas que estás insertando desde el trigger. Puedes impedir el insert completo pero no parcial.

Comment: ¿Cual es la razón para intentar hacer esto? ¿Qué es lo que buscas, no técnicamente, sino la necesidad de negocio que hay detrás de sto?

Comment: @PatricioMoracho en la pregunte te agregue lo que busco o el problema que tengo

Comment: Si leíste mi problema sabes de pronto que puedo hacer  como o una idea o algo ¿?

Comment: esto es un claro problema de negocio que deberia solucionar la app y no engendrando cosas en la db

Comment: Pero en este momento no puedo modificar la app :(

Comment: Mirá, tengo cero experiencia con SISS, lo que hay que entender es como actúa el paquete, ¿inserta atomicamente o por un batch de filas que incluye varios lotes?  lo que sí puedo decirte es que si es lo segundo, puedes disparar un error, simplemente viendo cuantos lotes distintos hay en `INSERTED`, el error "rollbaquea" la transacción completa, tu cliente tiene que ser capaz de procesar este error, pero lo que no puedes hacer, es insertar parte de las filas y la otra no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución para el escenario que planteas, puede ser un trigger cambiar la definición de tu trigger After, por Instead Of.

La particularidad de esta definición, es que el desencadenador, se inicia, en vez de la instrucción que lo desencadena, por tanto tienes que ser tú el que lance el insert.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.TblLotes (codLote int, Fecha date);
GO

CREATE TRIGGER dbo.Lotes_Restringidos
ON dbo.TblLotes
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS

;With Cte As
(
    Select ROW_NUMBER() Over(Order by t.fecha desc) as row
    , t.codLote
    , t.Fecha
    From inserted t
    )
    Insert into dbo.TblLotes (codLote, Fecha)
    Select c.codLote, c.Fecha from Cte c
    where Row=1;
GO
```

La definición del mismo, es idéntica, salvo por la marca INSTEAD OF en lugar de AFTER/FOR

Por tanto generamos un numerador de las filas que entran, y en la salida de la tabla de expresión común utilizamos únicamente la fila 1.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.TblLotes (codLote, Fecha)
values
(18291,'20190101'),
(18291,'20190102'),
(18291,'20190103');

GO

INSERT INTO dbo.TblLotes (codLote, Fecha)
values
(18292,'20190101'),
(18292,'20190102'),
(18292,'20190103');

GO

SELECT * FROM dbo.TblLotes;
```

[image: Resultado]

Si en la misma sentencia de inserción pudiesen ir varios lotes diferentes, solo hay que particionar el numerador de filas, por el codLote.

```
ALTER TRIGGER dbo.Lotes_Restringidos
ON dbo.TblLotes
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
;With Cte As
(
    Select ROW_NUMBER() Over(Partition by t.codLote Order by t.fecha desc) as row
    , t.codLote
    , t.Fecha
    From inserted t
    )
    Insert into dbo.TblLotes (codLote, Fecha)
    Select c.codLote, c.Fecha from Cte c
    where Row=1;
GO
```

La sentencia de inserción.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.TblLotes (codLote, Fecha)
values
(18293,'20190110'),
(18293,'20190101'),
(18293,'20190105'),
(18294,'20190108'),
(18294,'20190101'),
(18294,'20190103'),
(18295,'20190101');
GO
SELECT codLote, Fecha FROM dbo.TblLotes;
```

[image: Salida]

[Create Trigger](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)